# can ISP know your search queries on instagram?

Tags: networking, internet, search, isp, history

I've became a bit curious about what ISP can know about me. I'm already aware that ISP can read our search history and many other things but my question is that can ISP know the queries I search on apps such as instagram or telegram and find out my search history on those apps? and what kind of info can free vpns hide from your ISP?

Comment: As long as you see "https" at the start of your URL instead of plain "http" then you are good. Some browsers simply show a padlock icon but most sites should now prefer https over http. Sites that do not use https *will* be able to seen by your ISP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer: unless your computer is compromised, your ISP cannot see your search history on Instagram.**

In 2021, approximately 70% of websites use the https protocol (SSL/TLS). Instagram most definitely is one of these websites.

As such, your connection with the Instagram edge server is encrypted. While your ISP's network is partially responsible for routing your data, it cannot read it or make sense of it. Here is what your ISP knows about your visit to Instagram:

1. You visited Instagram.
2. You did it at some specific date and time.
3. You used the https protocol.
4. You sent *n* requests.

That's basically it. Because the http layer is encrypted, all your ISP really knows is the above info. They can't know anything like your search history or any data you *sent* to Instagram without some sort of subpoena, but then it becomes a legal matter.

I find the following infographic from [the Tor Project](https://www.eff.org/pages/tor-and-https) helpful. It applies to your situation:

[image: What various agents see about your connection]

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. if you have any info about the second part of my question too I would be glad to know.

Comment: @infinite VPNs are not useful in this scenario because the important information (data you sent to Instagram) is already private. If you want to hide the fact that you even used Instagram, you can use a VPN (although I don't recommend free ones for various reasons). If my answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted.